# Speed up page loading time

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pagespeed

Does any one know how they speedup page loading time (switch between sidebar article lists and load page contents instantly)?

```
http://gmailblog.blogspot.com
```

Or any suggestions for a better way ? [I already minified my js and css files] :)

Comment: Looks like the content is preloaded/cached or is being loaded via AJAX

Answer (score 2):

You can read [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11777192/web-tips-for-improving-speed-of-my-website/11777250#11777250) for know many method for improve your speedtime loading page.

Many good practises exist with [Yslow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) and [PageSpeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/?hl=fr).

For samples :

- Minimize HTTP Requests
- Use a Content Delivery Network
- Avoid empty src or href
- Add an Expires or a Cache-Control Header
- Gzip Components
- Put StyleSheets at the Top
- Put Scripts at the Bottom
- Avoid CSS Expressions
- Make JavaScript and CSS External
- Reduce DNS Lookups
- Minify JavaScript and CSS
- Avoid Redirects
- Remove Duplicate Scripts
- Configure ETags
- Make AJAX Cacheable
- Use GET for AJAX Requests
- Reduce the Number of DOM Elements
- No 404s
- Reduce Cookie Size
- Use Cookie-Free Domains for Components
- Avoid Filters
- Do Not Scale Images in HTML
- Make favicon.ico Small and Cacheable

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to look into AJAX. I would also recommend "PageSpeed Insights" plugin which provides many suggestions to improve overall loading speed.

Comment: using ajax also take little time to load pages, what is the technology  http://gmailblog.blogspot.com use ? Seems like using json and something that i don't know, but not pretty sure about json array can send this much of data instantly.

Comment: Json is not limited in the amount of data that it can store (within reason). The example you provided either uses AJAX that loads fast enough to seem instant or it loads all the data initially and then just uses jquery to make the transition.

Comment: Looking at the example closer it seems that the data in the article (text) is loaded as soon as it appears on screen (when you open the page or scroll down). When you click the link/article it appears instantly as it already has been loaded with AJAX.